# CEDET and Modern C++ : Nested Namespaces not working

Tags: c++, emacs, cedet

i trying to use CEDET for C++-Development
but especially modern C++ feature like nested
Namespaces like:

```
ns1::ns2::ns3 .. {
}
```

not working. I tried to find out if there existing
plans to implement support for modern C++ in CEDET?.
But no success.  So want to ask here. And Commits 
in original repository on savannah seems quite old.

I want to use CEDET. Because modern CLANG based
things using always a separate service process in
backend. I know I can try it by myself to put
support for modern C++ to CEDET. But its a complex
Emacs Lisp Project. And Im more fine with C++ as 
with Emacs Lisp.

Comment: Nested namespaces were in the c++ standard from the beginnig, it's not a _more modern_ feature.

Comment: Yes, I now but not with

Comment: Not with syntax: namespaceA::namespaceB::namespaceC::andSoOn {

Comment: I believe its possible in this way since C++14 or C++17!!

Comment: OK, seems you're right: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee3a76abef2eb7bc

Comment: Nested namespaces have been in the standard from the beginning.   But it ability to define nested namespaces using syntax `ns1::ns2::ns3` was not possible before C++17.   With regard to the question, ou'll have less chance of getting advice here about plans for cedet to support that (or C++17 more generally) than from the emacs people.

Comment: Sorry, I believe it was my mistake because I used "c++" tag. For sure it was a question for emacs community.